# AngularJS C directive using ng-class

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The title might not explain what I am trying to achieve, so I will elaborate here.
I have a directive that is restricted to a CSS class name (in this example flex-wrap).
But this class is not applied to the element until we actually have some data.

The HTML for that looks like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-class="{ 'loading': !controller.loadingRecent, 'flex flex-vertical flex-wrap': controller.recent.length }">
    <div class="col-md-12 row-title">
        <h1>Recent orders</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="!controller.recent.length">
        <div alert type="danger">
            No records have been found that match your search.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 tile-lg" ng-repeat="order in controller.recent" tile>
        <a class="box-shadow" id="{{ order.orderNumber }}" ui-sref="viewOrder({ orderNumber: order.orderNumber })" coloured-tile>
            <div class="text">
                <p>
                    <strong>{{ order.account.accountNumber }}</strong><br />
                    {{ order.account.name }}<br />
                    {{ order.raisedBy }}<br />
                    {{ order.orderNumber }}<br />
                    {{ controller.getDescription(order) }}<br />
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the **flex** classes are not applied until our **recent.length** is greater than 0. What I would like to happen is that when we have records, the CSS class is applied and so the angular directive that is associated with that class fires.

Instead, it doesn't do anything at the moment.
Does anyone know how I can get my directive to fire?

Here is my directive, just so you can see it.

```
.directive('flexWrap', ['$window', '$timeout', function ($window, $timeout) {

    // Sets the height of the element
    var setHeight = function (element) {

        // Declare our variables
        var row = element.parent().parent(),
            height = 630;

        // If our row is a row
        if (row.hasClass('row')) {

            // Get the height of the rest of the items
            height = height - getHeight(row);
        }

        console.log('height = ' + height);

        // Set our elements height
        element.css('height', height + 'px');

        console.log('we are about to set the width');

        // After we set the height, set the width
        setWidth(element);
    }

    // Gets the height to minus off the total
    var getHeight = function (element) {

        // Declare our variables
        var height = 0,
            children = element.children(),
            loopChildren = element.hasClass('row');

        // Loop through the element children
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

            // Get the child
            var child = angular.element(children[i]);

            // If the child is not a column
            if (!child.hasClass('columns')) {

                // If we need to loop the children
                if (loopChildren) {

                    // Get the height of the children
                    height += getHeight(child);

                    // Otherwise
                } else {

                    // Add the height of the child to 
                    height += child[0].offsetHeight;
                }
            }
        }

        // Return our height
        return height;
    };

    // Sets the width of the element
    var setWidth = function (element) {

        // After a short period
        $timeout(function () {

            // Get our last child
            var children = element.children(),
                length = children.length,
                lastChild = children[length - 1];

            // Work out the width of the container
            var position = element[0].getBoundingClientRect(),
                childPosition = lastChild.getBoundingClientRect(),
                width = childPosition.left - position.left + childPosition.width;

            var style = $window.getComputedStyle(lastChild, null);
            console.log(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
            console.log('--------------------------------');
            console.log(lastChild);
            console.log(position);
            console.log(childPosition);
            console.log(width);
            console.log('--------------------------------');


            console.log('width = ' + width);

            // Apply the width to the element
            element.css('width', width + 'px');
        }, 500);
    };

    // Resize the container
    var resize = function (element, width) {

        // If our width > 992
        if (width > 992) {

            // Resize our element
            setHeight(element);

        // Otherwise
        } else {

            // Set our element width and height to auto
            element.css('height', 'auto');
            element.css('width', 'auto');
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Get our window
            var window = angular.element($window),
                width = $window.innerWidth;

            // Bind to the resize function
            window.bind('resize', function () {

                // After half a second
                $timeout(function () {

                    // Get the window width
                    width = $window.innerWidth;

                    // Resize our element
                    resize(element, width);
                }, 500);
            });

            // Initial resize
            resize(element, width);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive declaration style (e.g. `restrict: "C"`) and an `ng-class` directive are not related to each other at all.

`ng-class` just adds/removes CSS class - it does not trigger a compilation/link of a directive that might be associated with these classes. In other words, it **does not** provide a way to dynamically instantiate a directive.

Your directive should handle the situation where data is not yet available. There are a number of ways to achieve that, via `$scope.$broadcast`/`$scope.$on` or via a service, or even via `$watch` - depending on any particular situation.

Comment: I was under the impression using broadcast was a bad idea?

Comment: @r3plica, whether it is or it isn't is not related to this question - but it is one of the options. The discussion of whether this is a good or a bad idea is broader than what my answer intended to be. The point is that `ng-class` does not work the way you expected

Comment: Fair enough, but I would hope that answers would provide 'best practice' answers rather than pointing to bad practices?

Comment: @r3plica, well, I might have, but your question wasn't about how to communicate to a directive that some async event happened. It was about how to dynamically compile/link using `ng-class` - admittedly, an XY question, but I thought was worthwhile addressing on its own

Comment: @r3plica, it is unrelated, but `$scope.broadcast` is not necessarily bad practice. It depends on a particular circumstance and saying unequivocally that it is bad practice is incorrect.